# Finding threading bottlenecks and optimizing for wall-time with perf

Tags: linux, multithreading, performance, profiling, perf

Sampling cpu-cycles with `perf record` is useful for finding optimization candidates if core-utilization is roughly constant. But for code that has multiple phases differing in parallelism counting cpu-cycles will emphasize heavily parallel phases while under-emphasizing sequential or limited-parallelism phases that impact wall-time. In short, naïve perf use may highlight the wrong limb of [amdahl's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law)

So the question is how to get `perf record`/`perf report` to find optimization candidates for reducing wall-time which could be anything from the hottest loop in consistently parallel code, over a moderately-parallel bottleneck to a long single-threaded phase.

Known workarounds that leave something to be desired:

- executeing the workload on a single core so that wall-time ≅ cpu-cycles
- profiling individual components separately

<sup>meta: this is a perf-specific followup [to a more general question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45251182/thread-utilization-profiling-on-linux)</sup>

Comment: Insofar as you have asked five questions and given 1000 answers, today's question is a rare event, isn't it?

Comment: If your parallel program has something like OpenMP or MPI parallelism and there is no oversubscribing and threads are bound to the cores (OMP_PROC_BIND, affinity) you can profile only cpu core with the main thread (`perf record -C 0 ./omp_program` or `perf report -C 0`) - it will partially remove the wrong limb. Second idea - do a diff between main thread and worker thread (`-C 1`). Third idea: add signalling using trace events into your parallel library and try to use `--switch-on`/`--switch-off` of [perf-report](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-report.1.html). Could you add example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[KDAB Hotspot](https://github.com/KDAB/hotspot) is a GUI that can analyze `perf record` output and also show context switches and core utilization if the profiles have been recorded with `-e sched:sched_switch --switch-events --sample-cpu`

[image]

Comment: no, and I don't think comments are appropriate for that kind of troubleshooting.